# Significato di "istituto" in una nota del libro "Parola di Dante"

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Parola di Dante* di Luca Serianni appare la nota seguente (grassetto mio):

> Altri editori come Inglese mettono a lemma *vincea*, documentato da una parte della tradizione, immaginando una «rima siciliana»: ma questo **istituto**, secondo l’opinione particolarmente autorevole di Castellani, non era operante nella Commedia: cfr. sopra, ﻿capitolo primo, nota ﻿20.

Non mi è chiaro il significato di "istituto" in questo testo. Ho letto il contenuto delle voci "istituto" nel [vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/istituto) e nel *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, ma non sono sicura di quale accezione sia quella adatta al contesto. Forse la seguente che si legge sul [GDLI](https://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI08/00000614.jpg)?

> Fenomeno  che  si  è  venuto  con­figurando  o  è  stato  accettato  o  considerato  come struttura   o   organismo   codificato   o   istituziona­lizzato.

Comment: Libro altamente raccomdabile del nostro recentemente scomparso grande maestro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A me sembra che la parola "istituto" in questa frase si riferisca alla "rima siciliana" (vale a dire parole che rimano solo se lette con in siciliano, ad esempio *vedere* e *servire*, che venivano entrambe lette in *-iri*). Il passo cioè vuol dire che, nell'opinione di Castellani, la rima siciliana non era usata nella *Commedia* e perciò *vincea* non può essere il lemma corretto (perché non rima).

L'uso di "istituto" in questo caso è un po' strano. Come suggerito dalla domanda, si tratta di un uso nel senso di "fenomeno istituzionalizzato". Probabilmente fa parte del linguaggio "accademico", almeno in questo sottocampo della linguistica. Si può vedere come anche alla voce [*Rima*](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/rima_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/) dell'enciclopedia Dantesca si parli della rima siciliana come di un "un legittimo istituto linguistico" (grazie a @DaG per averlo segnalato nei commenti).

L'unica cosa che mi turba in questa interpretazione è che mi pare ricordare dagli anni di scuola che Dante usasse (seppur di rado) la rima siciliana. Ma potrebbe essere che fosse solo in alcuni passaggi particolari come tributo, così come alcune terzine sono scritte in Provenzale in onore di Arnaut Daniel.

Comment: Sì, parla senz'altro della rima siciliana (come chiarisce ulteriormente la nota 20 del cap. 1 menzionata nel passo citato); penso che la domanda si riferisse a come mai sia definita “istituto”. Direi che @Charo dia già la risposta corretta: è un fenomeno linguistico a cui successivamente sono stati dati un nome e una codifica.

Comment: Quanto al merito della questione, vedo che nella [voce “Rima” dell'Enciclopedia dantesca](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/rima_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/) si dà effettivamente per scontato che ci siano rime siciliane nelle opere di Dante, compresa la Commedia, mentre a quanto pare i dantisti citati da Serianni (oltre a Castellani, Baldelli nell'Appendice dell'Enciclopedia dantesca, che però non riesco a trovare in rete) dissentono.

Comment: Sì, @DaG ha ragione: avevo già capito che si riferisse alla rima siciliana. Quello che non capisco è perché viene chiamata "istituto".

Comment: @Charo Effettivamente si tratta di un uso un po' strano. Ma farei notare che anche nella voce della Treccani citata da DaG si parla della rima siciliana come di "un legittimo istituto linguistico". Direi che la spiegazione data dal GDLI è l'unica possibile, anche se a me suona un po' innaturale.

Comment: Hai ragione, @DenisNardin: probabilmente si tratti di linguaggio tecnico. Ho cercato "istituto linguistico" su Google libri e ho trovato parecchie occorrenze: https://books.google.es/books?id=drmMDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT203&dq=%22istituto+linguistico%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit79Dq5Jb5AhUJuRoKHZMRCjg4FBDoAXoECAkQAQ

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?id=ixcNVK9lJsgC&pg=PA152&dq=%22istituto+linguistico%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit79Dq5Jb5AhUJuRoKHZMRCjg4FBDoAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22istituto%20linguistico%22&f=false, https://books.google.es/books?id=kcnVmcJU3jAC&pg=PA101&dq=%22istituto+linguistico%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizzJ6i5pb5AhUtwQIHHUshAUo4HhDoAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22istituto%20linguistico%22&f=false, https://books.google.es/books?id=mekfnwiP6VIC&pg=PA220&dq=%22istituto+linguistico%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiroJWY5Jb5AhVGyKQKHWd5Az44ChDoAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22istituto%20linguistico%22&f=false